# GitPython: how to commit updated submodule

Tags: python, git, git-submodules, gitpython

I have been at this for hours now, and although I have a feeling I'm close I can't seem to figure this out.

I'm trying to make a script that takes a git repository, updates a submodule in that repository to a specified version, and commits that change.

#### What works:

I can find the repository, get the submodule and check out the commit I want.

#### What doesn't work:

I can't seem to add the updated submodule hash so I can commit it.

### My Code:

```
repos = Repo('path/to/repos')
submodule = repos.submodule('submodule-name')
submodule.module().git.checkout('wanted commit')

diff = repos.index.diff(None)
```

At this point I can see the submodule-change. If I check sourcetree, I can see the changed submodule in the 'unstaged files'. 
The thing is, I have no clue how to stage the change so I can commit it.

#### What I have tried:

- If I commit using `repos.index.commit('')`, it creates an empty commit.
- If I try to add the path of the submodule using `repos.index.add([submodule.path])`, all files in the submodule are added to the repository, which is definately not what I want.
- If I try to add the submodule itself (which should be possible according to the docs) using `repos.index.add([submodule])`, nothing seems to happen.

Comment: Same problem here. API reference http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html#git.index.base.IndexFile.add mentions `repos.index.add([submodule])` but… yeah, nothing happens. A bug maybe? I reported it here: https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/issues/335

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways to add new submodule commits to the parent repository. One will use the `git` command directly, the other one will be implemented in pure-python.

All examples are based on the code presented in the question.

### Simple

```
repos.git.add(submodule.path)
repos.index.commit("updated submodule to 'wanted commit'")
```

The code above will invoke the `git` command, which is similar to doing a `git add <submodule.path>` in a shell.

### Pythonic

```
submodule.binsha = submodule.module().head.commit.binsha
repos.index.add([submodule])
repos.index.commit("updated submodule to 'wanted commit'")
```

The [`IndexFile.add(...)`](http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html#git.index.base.IndexFile.add) implementation adds whichever `binsha` it finds in the submodule object. This one would be the one in the parent repository's current commit, and not the commit that was checked out in the submodule. One can see the `Submodule` object as a singular snapshot of the submodule, which does not change, nor does not it know about changes to the submodule's repository.

In this case it seems easiest to just overwrite the `binsha` field of the submodule object to the one that is actually checked out in its repository, so adding it to the index will have the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks for this, works like a charm. Somewhat related: do you know how to show the current submodule hash? If I just switch branches and `update()` or `pull()`, the hash stays the same. I thought I understood git, but this doesn't seem to click for me :)

Comment: To answer my own question: `repos.submodule_update(force_reset=True)` will reset the submodule to where it should be according to the current branch. `submodule.module().head.commit` will then contain the sha of that commit in the submodule